# Can we search for questions based on number of votes?

Tags: support, search

After filtering the questions based on topic, can I filter them based on the number of votes a question has got? For e.g. I only want to see questions, on a specific topic such as c++, which have received more than 10 votes. Is there a way to do this today?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: @MartijnPieters geez you are too fast...

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can, you can set minimum number, or a range, by using the `score` operator:

```
score:10 [c++] is:q
```

will find questions in the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag with a score of 10 or up.

See the [search documentation in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).